# how to change url on function load with jquery / ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hashtag

didn't found any help with the search...

I'm going to do something like loading the content of an external php-file into a div container on my index.php;
to do so, I added a javascript call into the href of my hyperlinks that calls a function like this:

```
function contentloader(e){
switch(e){          
  case "profil":
    $("#content").load("profil.php");
    this.href('#profil');
    break;   
  case "einstellungen":
    $("#content").load("einstellungen.php");
    break;
  case "freunde":
    $("#content").load("freunde.php");
    break;     
}
```

}

well actually this works fine, but now I'm searching for a possibility to change the url of my index.php after loading such a content php file... 
for example it should be possible to safe a bookmark for
index.php#profile
index.php#einstellungen

does anybody has got a hint for me to search for or done something like that???
help appreciated!

(furthermore those external php file will include complex php code, mysql requests and so on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into window.location.href.hash. You should be able to use that to set the hash value on the URL. Look into http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/hash and http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Comment: thank you for your help! 
I tried this:

      function contentloader(e){
    switch(e){          
      case "profil":
        $("#content").load("profil.php");
          var Ziel = "!profil";
          window.location.hash = Ziel;
        break;   
      
    }   
  } 



but there is something I didn't get an answer on my own - when e.g. indexing directly index.php#!profil
it's opening the index.php but without loading the external content of profil.php - how does this gets possible, please be patient, I'm new to programming and stuff like that :D

thanks in advance!